# Unity desktop Ubuntu 15.04 freezes

Tags: unity, 15.04

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my HP ProBook 450 G2, but it is randomly freezing. I have a Intel and AMD GPU, but I have turned off AMD GPU and I only use Intel. Why this is happening? I have latest updates installed.

Answer (score 0):

It use to happen to me ,strangely got resolved by itself.The only thing i can guess is that my sources.list file(mirror of updates) was still pointing to Japanese Mirrors while i was in another country,when i came back to Japan,it never occurred,i had Ubuntu 14.04,maybe you can try 15.10 when its release,since it occurs often,i would advise you to go back to 14.04 if you can`t find a good solution

Comment: I have reinstalled amd drivers to see what hapens, if the problem will persist I will go back to 14.04. Thanks!